# Can't run my application says Unfortunately the application has stopped

Tags: android, xml, button, android-edittext, android-imageview

I made an android application that can download images from the web but when i run it its stops.It has no error here is my main class MainActivity.class `package com.downloadfiles;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnShowProgress;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ImageView my_image;


    EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);


    public static final int progress_bar_type = 0; 


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String i = edt.getText().toString();
        final String file_url  = i ;

        btnShowProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProgressBar);

        my_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);

        btnShowProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case progress_bar_type:
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            return pDialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }


    class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
    showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();

                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                String mak;
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
                String foe; 
                EditText form = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.formet);
                mak = form.getText().toString();
                foe = "Download file.";
                  OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/download/" +foe +mak);


                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;

                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                   output.write(data, 0, count);

                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();

                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }


        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // setting progress percentage
            pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
       }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
             String mak;
             EditText form = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.formet);
              mak = form.getText().toString();

            if (mak =="jpg")
              {
                String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/download/Download file." +"jpg";
                my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
              }
            else if (mak == "png")
              {
                String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/download/Download file." +"png";
                my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
              }
            else if (mak == "gif"){
                String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/download/Download file."+"gif";
                my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
            }
            else
              {Intent toNextPage = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        backgo.class); 
                startActivity(toNextPage);
    }
            }}}`
```

And here is my other class backgo.class

```
           `public class backgo extends Activity{
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sorryerror);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent toNextPage = new Intent(backgo.this,
                    MainActivity.class); 
            startActivity(toNextPage);

        }
    });}}`
```

and this is my layout activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:text="Enter the formet in which you want to download the file i.e mp3,jpg or mp4:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/formet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter the url from where you want to download file:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text = "http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/33400000/Naruto-evoliution-naruto-33413374-1600-1152.png"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Download File " />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/my_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my other layout sorryerror.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sorry the formet of your image you requested is not supported by the application we are very sorry..."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="233dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.37"
        android:src="@drawable/crying" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="166dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.01"
        android:text="Click here to go back" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String i = edt.getText().toString();
```

here is your problem. You never initialized `edt`.

you missed `edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1)`

also

if (mak =="jpg")

the content of a String in java needs `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` in order to be compared with another String. Using  `==` will compare the address of the Strings.

Change it in

```
if (mak.equals("jpg"))
```

Comment: thanks but my application still stops while displaying the image at the image view where I have place the if else conditions

Comment: is backgo.class an Activity ? Have you declared it inside the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: but there still seems to be something wrong my application downloads the application but if I enter a different format it stops it shuld go to the next class but it doesn't at this line else
              {Intent toNextPage = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        backgo.class); 
                startActivity(toNextPage);
    }

Comment: have you declared  backgo.class inside the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: how can I declare backgo.class in AndroidManifest.xml please help

Answer (score 1):

First, modify the `EditText` line in your `MainActivity` class as follows:

```
private EditText edt;
```

Then put this line in your `onCreate` method:

```
edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Now it should work.

Comment: thanks it works now but my application still stops while displaying the image at the image view where I have place the if else conditions can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); //<<<
```

you are trying to initialize EditText before calling `setContentView` for Activity. so initialize EditText inside onCreate  after setting layout for Activty.

```
EditText edt; //<< Declare here
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); //<< initilze here
  String i = edt.getText().toString();
  //...
```

**EDIT:-** also more `String i = edt.getText().toString();` in onClick of Button if you want to get text entered by user in EditText as:

```
my_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);
btnShowProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String file_url = edt.getText().toString();

        new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks but my application still stops while displaying the image at the image view where i have place the if else conditions

Comment: @user2435339 : ok then  show ur logcat result when app is crashing

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `edt` after  `setContentView` in `onCreate()`

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        Button btnShowProgress;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        ImageView my_image;


        EditText edt ;


        public static final int progress_bar_type = 0; 


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //Initialize editText Here        
            edt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

            String i = edt.getText().toString();
.......
```